# interface, interface client, vs inheritance, Software design principles, compoment packaging issue

Tags: c#, java, c++, design-principles

I came across one issue as to how to package interface, interface client and inheritance. That is, in the book below, author mentioned that Switachable is more appropriate to deploy with Switch together as a component, rather than Light.

**What I want to understand is the reasoning behind it (Both Switch and Switchable are packaged in one component, rather Switchable and Light) , and example if possible.**

I think there are cases where both scenarios are valid. One example that is oppoiste of that design is, IStream, FileStream are in one component, ISream client is in another component.

Below is from unclebob's agile in C# ch 33, p497.

[image]

Comment: @edutesoy please refer to my update at the beginning.

Comment: So... what's your question? The update is nice and all, but you haven't asked anything.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas would it make more sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Light` inherits from `Switchable`, it could also be deployed with `Switchable` - it seems, however, due to the naming, that the primary class interacting with the `Switchable` interface will be `Switch` - which means that the two are tightly-coupled: you should never put tightly-coupled class/interface definitions in separate assemblies.

You could also conceive of other `Switchable` classes, such as `Outlet` or a whole set of `Appliances`.  These could be added at a later date, and they would have nothing to do with `Light`, meaning that `Light` and `Switchable` aren't necessarily part of the same component.  However, the `Switch` class would still apply to these new classes and would apply.

(It is true that a different consumer of the `Switchable` interface could be conceived, but it would likely be an awkward adaptation, such as a `ToggleButton` that toggled the on/off state by remembering the last method called.  However, with the names chosen, `Switchable` still implies that a `Switch` could be involved.)

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.

I understand you point.

I think there are cases where both scenarios are valid. For example, IStream, FileStream are in one component, ISream client is in another component.  Futhermore, the names (i.e.Siwtch, Switable) is determined by the design, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Yeah, it does depend on the context of the interface - in the example of `IStream`, the client is going to be the specific case, whereas the `FileStream` isn't; a `Light` would be a specific case of `Swtichable`, where a `Switch` isn't.